# Add a Column from another table based on a select query from a separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking for some help here on adding a column of data to my query results from another table.

So the key on both tables is `customer_number`.

I have a query that is the following:

```
    SELECT [CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
          ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
          ,count(*) 'YEARS'
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[tablefromxlsimport$]
    group by  [CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
             ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
```

This returns the information I am looking for from the `tableformxlsimport$` but I would like to add a column of data from another table `fullcustomerlist$` based on the results of the query that will append a column of data that is `customer_Current_title`.

Hopefully I explained this correctly

Comment: Can't you JOIN the two tables?

Comment: `JOIN` on `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` and add the `customer_current_title` to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` (note, you'll have to specify `tableformxlsimport$.CUSTOMER_NUMBER` as it will then be ambiguous)

Comment: Can you be more specific? I think a left join is enough.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) may help you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below query:

```
 SELECT
      A.[CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
      ,A.[CUSTOMER_NAME]
      ,A.YEARS
      B.customer_Current_title
 FROM
   ( SELECT 
      A.[CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
      ,A.[CUSTOMER_NAME]
      ,count(*) 'YEARS'

  FROM [DB].[dbo].[tablefromxlsimport$] AS A
  group by  [CUSTOMER_NUMBER]
      ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
  ) AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.fullcustomerlist$ AS B on A.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

Comment: Updated teh code , please check.